# How to make this left sidebar visible on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

How to make this left sidebar visable on mobile devies?

http://demo.interface.club/limitless/demo/bs3/Template/layout_4/LTR/material/full/sidebar_default_collapse.html

I tried to add `class-sm-x` but this is still not visable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrapp it into `sidebar-mobile-main` class.

[How to make this left sidebar visable on mobile devies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15R3o.png)